# Are driver / kernel configuration support questions allowed?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to make my wireless work in Gentoo and because with Ubuntu it works just fine I guess this is a driver / kernel module misconfiguration. Previously I asked [a question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/my-admin-pages-do-not-show-is-this-a-pathing-problem) on Wordpress.SE and it was "closed as too localized". Would a question like this be "too localized"?

Answer (score 4):

I'm really surprised they closed that; too localized is almost always used to refer to time-sensitive questions, but even the part about "extraordinarily narrow circumstances" is debatable, it's completely possible somebody else would run into that problem

Anyway, kernel configuration stuff is fine, in my opinion. Don't worry about questions getting closed; if you think something makes sense here just ask, and we can discuss it if it gets closed and you disagree